# laravel migration:rollback gives error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have 2  migration tables and I migrated them succesfully. However I forgot to add something so I tried to rollback

```
  php artisan migrate:rollback
```

After this command I received these errors .

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table       'table name' (SQL: drop table `table name`)
>
> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table    'table name'

Migrations were successfull. However when I rolled back it could not found the table that I just migrated.

```
   <?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class OnlineDiyet extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('online_diyet',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');


        $table->string('bilgi');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('online_diyet');
}
```

}

and this is my seconda table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class Doctors extends Migration
  {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('doctors',function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->boolean('mailat',1);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();


    });        
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('online_diyet');

}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us your migration file?

Comment: here :http://hizliresim.com/OM599z

Comment: @AliYiğit the entire migration file including both up and down

Comment: i edited it  on question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second migration, inside the `down` method, you're droping the table `online_diyet` previously droping in your first migration.

it should be:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('doctors');
}
```